# Is there a way to read .xlxs files into my org with a dynamic sheet name?

Tags: lightning-web-components, dynamic, excel

I am currently able to read the data in an Excel file and convert it to JSON to be added to my org(Case Numbers and custom object IDs). However the sheet name in the Excel is currently hard coded as the default 'Sheet1'. I am looking for a way to be able to dynamically read the sheet name as many of the Excel files will have custom Sheet names.

Below is the function that I'm using.

```javascript
excelToJSON(file) {
   let reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = event => {
      let data = event.target.result;
      let workbook = XLS.read(data, {
         type: 'binary'
      });
      let XL_row_object = XLS.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"]);
      if (this.object === "Case To Product") {
         this.showCaseToProducts(XL_row_object);
      }
      if (this.object === "Case") {
         this.showCases(XL_row_object);
      }
   };

   reader.onerror = function(ex) {
      this.error = ex;
      this.dispatchEvent(
         new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error while reding the file',
            message: ex.message,
            variant: 'error',
         }),
      );
   };

   reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

UPDATED: SOLVED
I was able to solve the issue by creating an array and pushing the dynamic sheetnames into the array.

```
let mySheet = [];
mySheet.push(workbook.SheetNames);
let XL_row_object = XLS.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[mySheet[0]]);
```

Comment: Instead of an edit to the question, post the resolution as an answer (and you can also accept your own answer). This will help others who might have a similar issue find the fix more easily

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user seems to have solved the problem already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED: SOLVED I was able to solve the issue by creating an array and pushing the dynamic sheetnames into the array.

```javascript
let mySheet = [];
mySheet.push(workbook.SheetNames);
let XL_row_object = XLS.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[mySheet[0]]);
```